# Facebook graph api comments pagination

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm trying to get all the comments of post by using the following api url request:

```
$fb->get($yourPage.'/feed?fields=comments.limit(100)&limit=25&since=2017-7-01&until=2017-7-31', $accessToken);
```

But some posts have more than 500 comments which yields pagination '(next)' in the api response. Now I want to retrieve all the comments, so how do I paginate through the "comments" because I know how to paginate through posts through this code:

```
    $response = $fb->get($yourPage.'/feed?fields=comments.limit(500)&limit=25&since=2017-7-01&until=2017-7-31', $accessToken);
    $comments = $response->getGraphEdge();
    $totalcomments = array();

    if ($fb->next($comments)) {
//Do something if there is pagination in the posts
}
```

So how do I do the same for comments? I've searched alot on stack and google but no questions point to this... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each comments object includes a paging object for that:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2017-09-01T12:06:19+0000",
        "from": {
          "name": "xxx",
          "id": "1234"
        },
        "message": "xxx",
        "id": "1234"
      },
      ...
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "NzkZD",
        "after": "NzgZD"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/cccccc/comments?access_token=xxx&pretty=0&limit=2&after=NzgZD"
    }
  },
  "id": "xxx"
}
```

For every post you get, you need a subroutine (for example, with a recursive function) to use the "next" parameter in a separate API call to get all comments.

Comment: Doesn't it have a function to just execute the 'next' parameter just like it does for the posts ; Like this $fb->next($comments)?

Comment: no, but you can just $fb->get with the next parameter, it should be pretty much the same

Comment: Can  you provide the proper code for that? Just to save my time?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service, we don´t spend OUR time to save YOUR time ;) you should have everything you need already, just do the additional api calls with the next parameter per post.

Comment: I don't know how to access that next parameter.